# Clone Octopus Project

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy

I am trying to clone an octopus project using Octopus.Client. This is the code I'm using:

```
$OctopusURI = "http://localhost:8080"
$apikey = "API-SO7PMXWLYU6RPCUKMWK22GBKYQ"

$endpoint = new-object -TypeName Octopus.Client.OctopusClient(New-Object Octopus.Client.OctopusServerEndpoint($OctopusURI,$apikey))

$repository = new-object Octopus.Client.OctopusRepository $endpoint

$newproject = New-Object Octopus.Client.Model.ProjectResource

$OriginalProject = $repository.Projects.FindByName($projectToClone);

Write-Output $OriginalProject

$properties = [ordered]@{
    Name = $Project_Name
    Description = $Project_Description
    ProjectGroupId = $OriginalProject.ProjectGroupId
    LifecycleId = $OriginalProject.LifecycleId
}

$newproject = New-Object Octopus.Client.Model.ProjectResource -Property $properties

$endpoint.post("~/api/projects?clone=" + $OriginalProject.Id, $newproject)
```

And this is the error I'm getting

> Cannot find an overload for "post" and the argument count: "2".

This is the definition of the method : post

```
void Post[TResource](string path, TResource resource, System.Object pathParameters) 
TResponse Post[TResource, TResponse](string path, TResource resource, System.Object pathParameters) 
void Post(string path), void  IOctopusClient.Post[TResource](string path, TResource resource, System.Object pathParameters) 
TResponse IOctopusClient.Post[TResource, TResponse](string path, TResource  resource, System.Object pathParameters), 
void IOctopusClient.Post(string path)
```

Please, help clarify what the third parameter is supposed to be

Comment: As it takes and object, and I don't think you need to supply anything further than what you included in your example - it has to be worth supplying a null value for pathParameters.

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter is an object defining substitution parameters if the first parameter is a URL template. Since you are using a fully formed URL, you can pass in null.

Example of using subsitution (C#):

```
client.Post(client.RootDocument.Links["Projects"], project, new { clone=originalPrj.Id })
```

If you use Visual Studio and try it out in C#, it will show you the documentation in the intellisense and that the third parameter is optional. I guess PS doesn't support those optional parameters.